# setSate in ComponentDidmount get not defined in reactjs

Tags: state, setstate

I have code like below. And I get error "arrUsers is not defined". I do not know what I wrong

> class UserManage extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        arrUsers: []
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await getUser('ALL');
    if (response & response.errCode === 0) {
        // this.setState({
        //     arrUsers: response.users
        // })
        this.setState({
            arrUsers: response.users
        }, () => {
            console.log('Get User from node js using callback: ', arrUsers)
        })
        console.log('Get User from node js: ', arrUsers)
    }
}


render() {
    console.log('Render get User from node js: ', this.state)
    return ( ...)
}
```